# A 2016-2020 mecha anime where they fight in a pod while the robots are in outer space

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

The main character has orange hair. There was a special school they attend to fight the villains. They fought in a pod while the robots are in outer space.

I remember when the villain was captured. She turned from a beautiful young girl to a very old woman.